# NodeJS Stop listening to a certain port

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to 'reconnect' to a server with different values and I have this right now.

```
   var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        if(url!="close"){
            server.on("listening", function () { server.close(); });
            var file = engine.files[indexOfMovie];
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);
            file.createReadStream().pipe(res);
        }
    });
    server.listen('2020');
```

So what I need to do is let the listener which is already listening stop when a new server is defined and afterwards start the new server.

How can this be done in NodeJS?